# Can not use Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I can not successfully use the Datatables library.

my includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>lib/bootstrap-4.3.1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>lib/DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>lib/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>lib/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>CSS/default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>JS/script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>JS/script2.js"></script>
```

I downloaded datatables [here](https://datatables.net/download/) (Download pill).
And jquery [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js).

The script2.js script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").DataTable();
});
```

The table:

```
<table class="display">
    <caption class="text-center">Employés</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Fonction</th>
            <th>Téléphone</th>
            <th>Courriel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($employees as $employee) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= utf8_encode($employee['nom']) ?></td>
            <td><?= utf8_encode($employee['prenom']) ?></td>
            <td><?= utf8_encode($employee['fonction']) ?></td>
            <td><?= utf8_encode($employee['telephone']) ?></td>
            <td><?= utf8_encode($employee['courriel']) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Fonction</th>
            <th>Téléphone</th>
            <th>Courriel</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

There is some warnings/errors:

```
jquery-3.5.0.js:4046 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery.phpPrefilter is not a function TypeError: jQuery.phpPrefilter is not a function
jquery-3.5.0.js:5032 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.phpPrefilter is not a function
```

But it does not work. I tried to follow the order of the includes. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: If I add a alert("some message") between the second and the third line of datatables.j. The alert is never displayed. So I guess there is a problem when calling Datatable function at line 2.

Comment: @Sevia, you are loading two DataTables library. Try to remove the last one or whichever has the latest version.

Comment: @ubuntux are you sure or can you be more specific please? datatables.js is just the script of 3 lines where I call Datatables(). I think I loaded the datatables css and js and the jquery js.

Comment: @ubuntux thanks for your involvement. Are you able to make this working by following your suggestion?

Comment: What warnings/errors are you getting in your browser console, when the page loads? Add that info to your question. (Try F12 to open the console, or google for your specific browser.)

Comment: @andrewjames thanks, I posted the log file. There is 1 uncaught error and 2 warnings

Comment: @Sevia, on your includes, notice line 4 which has the code `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>lib/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>`, and line 8 having `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if ($prefix) echo '../'; ?>JS/datatables.js"></script>`. This is what I was referring to earlier.

Comment: Thanks @ubuntux but the include at line 8 does not include the datatables library but only a js script of mine where I wrote the second block of code that you can see in the question. I will rename that. Do you think there is a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that solved my problem was to use [jquery-3.5.0.slim.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.slim.js) intead of [jquery-3.5.0.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js).